# Extract_message in python throws AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python

I am trying to extract .msg files in a folder,

```
    folder_data = glob.glob(r"E:/msg_format/*.msg")
    for p in range(0,1):
        msg = extract_msg.Message(folder_data[p])
        regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')      
        l6 = msg.subject
        l7 = msg.body                    
        Text = l6 +" "+l7
```

This throws an error, in the line

```
          extract_msg.Message(folder_data[p])
```

if e.message == 'not an OLE2 structured storage file':

AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute 'message'

Not sure why, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

> extract_msg.Message(folder_data[p])

That line is asking for "message" attribute to get the Message object from folder_data[p]. When you do

> if e.message == 'not an OLE2 structured storage file'

that is also looking for that attribute, so thats why is throwing **AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute 'message'**.
You can check if object has certain attribute with the builtin `hasattr()`, like this:

```js
if hasattr(e, "message"):
  if e.message == 'not an OLE2 structured storage file':
    // do something
```

To fix the first part of your code, you can do something like this:

```js
folder_data = glob.glob(r"E:/msg_format/*.msg")
for p in range(0,1):
  if hasattr(folder_data[p], "message"):
    msg = extract_msg.Message(folder_data[p])
    regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')      
    l6 = msg.subject
    l7 = msg.body                    
    Text = l6 +" "+l7
  else:
    // do something to control exception
```

Hope it works!